# How can I add a column to a data frame that counts upwards based on the values in another column?

Tags: r, count

I want to add a new column to my existing data frame that counts upwards from 1 based on the Time column. The Time data is in hourly measurements over 24 hours, starting from 1400 (in this example). As the Time data occasionally skips some hourly intervals (such as from 1800 to 2100 in this example), I need the count column to also skip by the same degree.

My data currently looks like this:

```
X ID    Measure  Time  
1 793   38.3      14  
2 793   37.9      15  
3 793   38    16  
4 793   38.4      17  
5 793   38.7      18  
6 793   38.9      21  
7 793   38.3      22  
8 793   38.1      23  
9 793   38    0  
10 793  38.3      1  
11 793  38.5      2  
12 793  37.8      3  
13 793  37.4      4  
14 793  37.4      5  
15 793  37.7      6  
16 793  37.8      7  
17 793  37.9      8  
18 793  37.2      9  
19 793  38    10  
20 793  38.4      11  
21 793  37.8      12  
22 793  37.8      13
```

I need it to look like this:

```
X ID    Measure  Time  Time2  
1 793   38.3      14   1  
2 793   37.9      15   2  
3 793   38    16   3  
4 793   38.4      17   4  
5 793   38.7      18   5  
6 793   38.9      21   8  
7 793   38.3      22   9  
8 793   38.1      23   10  
9 793   38    0    11  
10 793  38.3      1    12  
11 793  38.5      2    13  
12.793  37.8      3    14  
13 793  37.4      4    15  
14 793  37.4      5    16  
15 793  37.7      6    17  
16 793  37.8      7    18  
17 793  37.9      8    19  
18 793  37.2      9    20  
19 793  38    10   21  
20 793  38.4      11   22  
21 793  37.8      12   23  
22 793  37.8      13   24
```

I'm not sure how to add a count that accounts for the gaps in the Time data. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base-R solution:

```
# read data
df <- read.table(
  text = "
  X ID    Measure  Time
  1 793   38.3      14
  2 793   37.9      15
  3 793   38        16
  4 793   38.4      17
  5 793   38.7      18
  6 793   38.9      21
  7 793   38.3      22
  8 793   38.1      23
  9 793   38        0
  10 793  38.3      1
  11 793  38.5      2
  12 793  37.8      3
  13 793  37.4      4
  14 793  37.4      5
  15 793  37.7      6
  16 793  37.8      7
  17 793  37.9      8
  18 793  37.2      9
  19 793  38        10
  20 793  38.4      11
  21 793  37.8      12
  22 793  37.8      13 ",
  header = TRUE
)

df$time2 <- c(1, diff(df$Time)) # differences between time entries
df$time2[df$time2 < 0] <- df$time2[df$time2 < 0] + 24 # replace difference of -23 hours at midnight
df$time2 <- cumsum(df$time2) # cummulative sum
```

We simply build the difference between the time entries and sum them up. if there's a negative difference from a day-change we add 24 to it. This solutions assumes the time entries are ordered

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(diff = cumsum(ifelse(c(1, diff(Time)) < 0, 24 + c(1, diff(Time)), c(1, diff(Time)))))
```